# Passing error message from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to do something like below.

```
//Controller

if(Session["UserId"]!=null)  // If user is logged in
{
   return View(db.Orders.ToList());
}
else
{
    //return a error message on the same view
}
```

how can i do this??

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would use a view model and have a property for error message there. If you are not using a view model, you could add a value to your ViewBag and use it in the view:

```
if(Session["UserId"]!=null)  // If user is logged in
{
    return View(db.Orders.ToList());
}
else
{
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "My error message";
}
```

In your view you would use the added value somewhere:

```
<p>@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need this, but what I would do is to throw the `HttpException` and let my ajax call handle it.

Example:

```
try
{
  // DO SOMETHING....
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Note: I use Bad Request status code for this example. You can choose what is specific for your needs...
  throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message, ex.InnerException); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Error", ex.Message);
```

There is  a default validation summary div that display the exception encountered.
Otherwise the viewbag would be preferable as you create your own display.